# How to decide which unicode character is a word seperator?

Tags: string, unicode

In most text editors, like notepad-plus-plus and vscode, when you double click on a character, they will select the whole word. I am curious how to implement that, this function(in Python) could be:

```
separators = 'some characters' # word separators
def select_word_at_offset(line, offset):
    line_length = len(line)
    if offset < 0 or offset > line_length:
        raise RuntimeError('offset is not a valid index of line')
    
    # ignore the cases when you double click on a word separator

    start_index = offset
    end_index = offset

    # look left to find the start index
    while start_index >= 0:
        if line[start_index] in separators:
            break
        start_index -= 1

    # look right to find the end index
    while end_index < line_length:
        if line[start_index] in separators:
            break
        end_index += 1
    return start_index + 1, end_index - 1
```

It's easy to do that if you just consider ASCII characters, but to support unicode, I have to decide which unicode character should be considered as a word separator. Whether to use a whitelist or a blacklist, it's gonna be a very long list.

So, is there any easy way to cover all unicode word seperators? And how did these editors do that?

Comment: Did you try a regex? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: See the [Unicode Word Boundary Rules](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-37.html#Word_Boundaries). I don't know if Python has a core module that implements that algorithm or if you have to install one (Or write one yourself if you're a masochist)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Shawn,  [Unicode Word Boundary Rules](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/tr29-37.html#Word_Boundaries) helps a lot, I read [this post](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/06/perl-v5-22-adds-fancy-unicode-word-boundaries/) and looks like perl already got it, I never learned perl, so still need some time to confirm that.

And I found out [vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/common/model/wordHelper.ts) use these characters as word separators:

```
export const USUAL_WORD_SEPARATORS = '`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:\'",.<>/?';
```

Apparently, they didn't consider non-English language symbols, like `。`, which indicates the end of a sentence in Chinese.